# linux shell copy paste adds ~0 and 1~ symbols to string

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-16.04, copy-paste

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.
Lately, I experience the following strange behavior when copy pasting via the clipboard, e.g. let's say I want to clone some repository. So, I copy the following string:

"https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow"

And then paste it to my shell after a `git clone` using ctrl+shift+v. I would expect:

`$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow`

But instead I see

`$ git clone ~0https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow1~`

This does not happen all the time and I have not yet figured out, what causes this annoying behavior. Anyone else experiencing this and has someone found out how to get rid of it?

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196098/copy-paste-in-xfce4-terminal-adds-0-and-1) answers your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -3):

Try to find the solution here: http://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3207
TL;DR seems like bug in the Ubuntu packages. 
You can copy text selecting it with the mouse and pressing scroll button to paste, the way to avoid your troubles at now.